# Android Togglebuttons organized as a pyramid?

Tags: android, layout, togglebutton

I want 7 togglebuttons to be organized in a pyramid, like this:

```
---b---
--b-b--
-b---b- 
b-----b
```

where b represents a togglebuton and - represents an empty space. I also wnat the whole pyramide to fill the width of it's parent. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use RelativeLayout.

Make the top button to have layout_centerHorizontal="true" and will be set in the top middle.
For the next row, use for both buttons layout_below="@id/id_of_your_top_button" so they both would be aligned below your top button, and then, for both use layout_toLeftOf="@id/id_of_your_top_button" and toRight respectively, so they would be positioned to the left and to the right of your top button. Just repeat fot 3rd and 4th row.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/second_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/top"
/>
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/second_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/top"
/>

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/third_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/second_left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/second_left"
/>
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/third_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/second_right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/second_right"
/>

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/fth_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/third_left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/third_left"
/>
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/fth_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/third_right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/third_right"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works lika a charm....almost....but the fth_left and fth_right does not fit into the width of the parent. :( How can I set all buttons to have the same width AND fill the width of the parent?

Comment: The only quick suggestion I can give you, is to calculate the width of a ToggleButton in the activity and laying out the pyramid programmaticaly, replacing all wrap_content in ToggleButtons to whatever width value you've got.